# Where is Oracle's (Sun's) JDK/JRE installed on Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion?

Tags: java, macos

Where does Oracle (Sun) install their JDK/JRE on Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` according to the [Mac JDK Uninstall Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jdk.html#uninstall).

Comment: Are you running JDK 1.7 on Mountain Lion?

Comment: I see I got 1.4, 1.5 and 1.6 but no 1.7

Comment: @AviramSegal: you've probably installed Java for OS X, which built and distributed by Apple, not the Oracle JRE/JDK.

Comment: Only true for the JDK, the JRE is at `/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/` as http://stackoverflow.com/a/21068094/461597 pointed out.

Comment: You can also try `$(/usr/libexec/java_home)` which will dynamically find the path to your java installation. source: https://www.baeldung.com/java-home-on-windows-7-8-10-mac-os-x-linux

Answer (score 14):

The Oracle Java SE downloads at: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/index.html

install here on Maverick at least:

```
/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/
```

this JRE is entirely separate from the ones that Apple has installed, which are under `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/` as another answer mentioned.

Answer (score 9):

If you setting the JRE path in something like Eclipse you'll need to point to the /home directory i.e

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<Replace with version>/Contents/Home`

Answer (score 8):

Some of the other answers might be correct but this is what worked for me (which is different and up to date as of January 2016) when installing it on a new computer at the office.

The path as mentioned in another answer is

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<Replace with version>/Contents/Home
```

Here however is a visual guide to getting there, because you can find many directories named "Library". Make sure you are here

[image]

then click into *JavaVirtualMachines*

[image]

If you are doing a new setup and just downloaded Android studio, they might have sent you to "Download Java for OS X 2015-001" at https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US 
 That gives you version 1.6.0

[image]

That won't work!!!!

I got the error that I needed JDK 7.0 or newer.

I looked for a newer version and found this link from Oracle
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

[image]

I installed it, then selected that one. And it worked

[image]

Answer (score 7):

On my system, evaluating `which java` leads me to `/usr/bin/java`. This in turn is a symlink to:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

In case it's relevant, `java -version` tells me I have `1.6.0_37` installed.

Comment: I have the same behavior. I'm trying to figure out how to go from the command `java` to the actual executable. I can find `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java` the same way you did, but it is just an executable, not a symlink.

Comment: FYI, the Apple distributed Java for OS X ends up in /System/Library/Java

Answer (score 1):

The JDK/JRE as mentioned in previous answers is located in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<version>/Contents/Home/. The JRE is dir under this Home.
Interestingly browsers doesn't use files from this location for java applet plugin. The location used by browsers is /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/.
In fact if you run JRE installer, it updates the files in this location rather than JDK/JRE location.

Answer (score 0):

Enough answers here, but I'm **JUST** adding a way to find it by yourself

```
$ sudo find / -name Java
/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java
/Library/Java
/private/var/root/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java
/System/Library/Java
/Users/prayagupd/Library/Application Support/Oracle/Java
```

To be more specific,

```
$ sudo find / -name jdk*
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk
/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/jdkAnnotations.jar
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/jre/jdk
/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/jdkAnnotations.jar
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_76.jdk
```

You see `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` is the place you need to look inside.

And `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk<version>.jdk/Contents/Home/` is your `JAVA_HOME`

```
$ ls -ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_76.jdk/Contents/Home/
total 39776
    8 -rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel      3339 Dec 18  2014 COPYRIGHT
    8 -rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel        40 Dec 18  2014 LICENSE
    8 -rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel       114 Dec 18  2014 README.html
  216 -rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel    110114 Dec 17  2014 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt
  344 -rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel    173559 Dec 18  2014 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
    0 drwxrwxr-x  44 root  wheel      1496 Feb 28 20:13 bin
    0 drwxrwxr-x   9 root  wheel       306 Feb 28 20:13 db
    0 drwxrwxr-x   9 root  wheel       306 Feb 28 20:13 include
    0 drwxrwxr-x  10 root  wheel       340 Feb 28 20:13 jre
    0 drwxrwxr-x  14 root  wheel       476 Feb 28 20:13 lib
    0 drwxrwxr-x   5 root  wheel       170 Dec 18  2014 man
    8 -rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel       502 Dec 18  2014 release
39184 -rw-rw-r--   1 root  wheel  20061067 Dec 18  2014 src.zip
```

Answer (score -2):

The version 8 release from Oracle (1.8.0_40-b25) can be found at:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

FYI: Oracle is not following the practice of making /Library/Java/Current (etc) a link to the latest installed java.

Below is my method of keeping up with versions over time:  from my .zshrc file:

```
108 JAVA_6_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home
109 JAVA_7_HOME=/Library/Java/Current
110 JAVA_8_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home
111 
112 export JAVA_6_HOME
113 export JAVA_7_HOME
114 export JAVA_8_HOME
115 
116 export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_8_HOME
117 
118 PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
119
```