# What is the path to the JRE file?

Tags: macos, operating-system, java

I am looking for the path the the JRE file on Mac OS X 10.6.8.
Or is there no such file?
Is JRE just slang for an idea or concept?
Java Runtime Environment is a real thing.

Does it have a file?
I am installing something that asks for the path to the JRE file
http://www.boonex.com/trac/dolphin/wiki/RayMediaServerInstallation

Comment: This link will help you [How install a specific jdk on Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1577014/how-install-a-specific-jdk-on-mac-os-x)  **AND** [JRE 7 Installation for Mac OS X](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/mac/mac-jre.html)

Comment: To update this for future use: If you need Java for development, you want the JDK not the JRE. I recently found a great JDK manager at https://www.jenv.be/. Hope  this helps.

Answer (score 22):

On the mac, set JAVA_HOME to "/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home"

The JRE is not a file.  The JRE is the java runtime environment and is made up of many files. The convention for java is to specify the JAVA_HOME.  That is a directory containing a bin folder.

Comment: -1 - This does not answer the Question that was asked.  He is explicitly asking about a "file" ... not a directory.

Comment: He explicitly asked for the path the to the JRE. What I originally did not give was explanation of what the JRE is.  Or do you think I shouldn't have answered the question at all.

Comment: In addition, Oracle stores Java 8 (JRE & SDK 1.8) in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/.  Reference this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13918476/447949

Comment: This worked for me to (OS X 10.10.2). This should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: @StephenC Since when is a directory not a file?

Comment: Since the 1970's.  Or earlier.  But certainly the 1970's.  What happens when you try to run "rm" on a directory or "rmdir" on a file on a Linux / UNIX system?  Now ... both directories and files have paths, and the syntax for directory and file paths is (almost) the same.

Comment: @ArisBartee - Actually, I think you should have at least have pointed out that the OP had messed up his terminology, and misread the installation documentation to boot!.  I suspect that his poor understanding of the terminology is the real reason he misunderstood the documentation.  (Alternatively, if he really thinks / thought the JRE is a file ... then that needs to be corrected too ... for the same reason.)

Answer (score 21):

In Mac you can find Java JRE's installed in the following folders

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/

Example
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home.

Comment: Not strictly true, JDK != JRE

Answer (score 19):

After installing the latest JRE8 (as of today update 131), do the following :

In your `.bash_profile` add the following

```
export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home'
```

Then add that to your path `export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME`. Save and open a new terminal. Type `java -version`. You should see output like this:

```
->java -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: on a related note, if you need a path to the JDK (located elsewhere by default installation), I found this export statement avoids hard-coding the path: `export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"` Make sure you edit the version number if needed.

Comment: UPDATE: Here's what I have now in my `.zshrc` config file


# To find JAVA_HOME, run "$(dirname $(readlink $(which javac)))/java_home"
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home --version 16` #keep backticks

Answer (score 4):

On **El Capitan** with Java 8, here is a way to check the path of jre. 
Go "System Preference/Java", then go third tab "Java" and click "View". Then you can get the JRE path, which is `/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/`

Comment: The View button is greyed out here.

Answer (score 4):

Run `/usr/libexec/java_home` in a terminal. It will return the path that corresponds to $JAVA_HOME for your Mac's default Java installation. Attach `/jre` to this path to get the Java runtime environment (JRE) path.

Example:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home
```

JRE would be `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre`

To verify:

```
$ ls -al /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
total 552
drwxr-xr-x  10 root  wheel     340 Apr  2  2019 .
drwxr-xr-x  15 root  wheel     510 Apr  2  2019 ..
-r--r--r--   1 root  wheel    3244 Apr  2  2019 COPYRIGHT
-r--r--r--   1 root  wheel      44 Apr  2  2019 LICENSE
-r--r--r--   1 root  wheel      46 Apr  2  2019 README
-rw-r--r--   1 root  wheel  112748 Mar 14  2019 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt
-r--r--r--   1 root  wheel  149725 Apr  2  2019 THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
-r--r--r--   1 root  wheel     955 Apr  2  2019 Welcome.html
drwxr-xr-x  13 root  wheel     442 Apr  2  2019 bin
drwxr-xr-x  98 root  wheel    3332 Apr  2  2019 lib
```

This also works with any OpenJDK installation:

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

#### Versions

If you have multiple JREs or JDKs installed, you can obtain $JAVA_HOME for a specific version using the `-v` option:

```
$ % /usr/libexec/java_home -v 11  
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home
```

### Tipp

To set the JAVA_HOME environment variable, use

```
$ export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_212.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Answer (score 2):

If you installed jre by dmg.

You can find your "java" at

> /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java

and you can check version by command:

> /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java -version

Answer (score 1):

The `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home` answer used to be correct.

With Oracle Java 8 (and later?) on MacOSX Sierra the `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home` doesn't exist.

The answer for `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` is much closer.  For the JDK at `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Content/Home`, for instance, just add `/jre` to the end of that path for the JRE.