# Multiple Java Executables on New Machine

Tags: java, macos, macos-high-sierra, java-home, homebrew-cask

#### TLDR; Why does brew/cask (or maybe even the native installer) install multiple executables for java?

System Data:

MacOS 10.13 / High Sierra

I am setting up a new dev machine and before installing java ran the following command: `java` and was told that no binary could be found.

From here I ran `brew cask install java`. At this point java became executable and running `which java` provided me a path at usr/bin/java. This location unsurprisingly turns out to be a link to

`/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`

Out of curiosity I ran: `/usr/libexec/java_home` which returned:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`

I *believe* that is the typical location for the JAVA_HOME environment variable. However, when looking at the path which the java bin points to you will notice that the location are different. `JAVA_HOME/bin` points to a location in `/Library` while `which java` points to a location in `System/Library` I understand that there is a general rule in Mac computing that says that /System resources are basic machine settings that shouldn't be monkeyed with and that /Library resources are for user installed and managed software, but I do not understand why I would have the exact same executable stored in two places.

My question is, why is the same software installed at two different places and why would `JAVA_HOME/bin` point to one binary while `which java` would point to another?

---

Resources I Used Before Asking:

[what does mac os /Library folder store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286571/what-does-mac-os-library-folder-store)

[Where is Oracle's (Sun's) JDK/JRE installed on Mac OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13918475/where-is-oracles-suns-jdk-jre-installed-on-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion)

Comment: My guess - not being a Mac guy but having had to deal with this on a Mac before - is that this is how Macs have to be configured to run with Java.  It's a royal pain in the neck.

Comment: Read this blog post: http://mattshomepage.com/articles/2016/May/22/java_home_mac_os_x/

Comment: You question could be possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120745/understanding-oracles-java-on-mac/15133344

Comment: @NaveenKumar Thank you so much. This is totally a duplicate your second link answered my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a duplicate and the answer comes from user bdash who deserves all credit for answering in a full and clear manner. Thanks to Naveen Kumar who provided this pointer. For full answer go to:

[Understanding Oracle's Java on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15120745/understanding-oracles-java-on-mac/15133344)

The short answer for folks coming to this page from google is that the items in /System/Library are stubs and not the real java executable. The true location for the JDK is the one exposed by /usr/libexec/java_home.